# click() not being invoked on link element

Tags: javascript

This is the code:

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = name;
    link.href = uri;
    link.click();
```

For some reason, the download is not being invoked in IE. It works in Firefox, Chrome and Opera, but not in IE. I am using the newest version of IE 11.

I tried setting a click event handler on the link that would alert something just so I can see if the link is being clicked at all, but nothing happened.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you want to execute this in this way?

Comment: @Mouser I am trying to automatically invoke a download of a file, as a part of some other functionality.

Comment: have you tried using jQuery? It is cross-browser compatible and should also work in IE 11.

Comment: `location.href = uri` should trigger the download if it's a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, it seems that link.click() is not working in IE because IE doesn't know on which element it is supposed to fire click event (even though it has a direct reference to it). It works in other browsers because they can accurately "guess" where to fire it.

I managed to solve the problem by adding a link element to the DOM, then referencing it via query selector and finally calling a click() method on it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to test IE11 right now, but try:

```
(function() {
var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.setAttribute("href", uri);

    var dispatch = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    dispatch.initEvent("click", true, true);
    a.dispatchEvent(dispatch);
}());
```